# Why have been the Selenium Python API Documentation taken down partially?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What happened to the Selenium Python API Documentation?

Is anybody aware why the [Selenium Python API Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html#selenium-documentation) has been taken down partially?

[image: Selenium Python API Documentation]

Comment: Ask the maintainers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Almost all the Selenium maintainers are pretty much frequent and active within the mentioned tags. I'm sure someone will help with the info.

Comment: To be more specific, I mean: ask them _elsewhere_ (e.g. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues)? This kind of support-related query doesn't tend to lead to durable SO value.

Comment: Is your concern depreciation?

Comment: @MosheSlavin Yup, somewhat :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally there is a clarification now as in the discussion [[ Bug]: What happened to the Selenium Python API Documentation?](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10165) *@titusfortner* confirmed:

> Looks like we tried to update Sphinx version and something wasn't happy. I regenerated 4.1 docs with an older version of Sphinx and it looks like it's working now.